# How to Refresh <pre> with jQuery & Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can you please let me know how I can refresh only a `<pre>` Element of a page with jQuery & Ajax? I am not interested to send any data to ajax but I need to REFRESH  the `<pre>` after adding value to the element
 Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Proweb/2mmrx/1/) link of what I am doing and this the code

```
Type Here: <input type="text" id="textbox1"/>
<p>
<pre></pre>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#textbox1").keyup(function(){
     var textinput = $('#textbox1').val().substring(0,50);
        $("pre").text( textinput );
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what does refresh mean here ?

Comment: Please define `REFRESH`

Comment: Honestly I couldn't find any better term for it as pre already updating  on key up  let say re loading things to pre again

Comment: @Behseini like --> http://jsfiddle.net/2mmrx/2/

Comment: @Tushar, I like your idea but what I need to do is reloading the pre lets think send the textbox value to ajax and return it to page from there

Comment: @Behseini your Question says `not interested to send any data to ajax`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try <kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2mmrx/2/)</kbd>

```
 $("pre").stop(true, true).hide(0).fadeIn().text(textinput);
```

Comment: is it possible doing something like this: $.ajax({url:"val", data: { value: val }, success: function